# GPIO output impedance from Microcontroller Datasheet

Tags: microcontroller, gpio

I am building an application around the Texas Instruments TUSB3210 USB Microcontroller (Now obsolete, not on market)

I referred to [this datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tusb3210.pdf) to try and estimate the maximum current that can be safely drawn from each GPIO pin of this controller. The information that I could gather in this regard is

Each I/O port has Schmitt-trigger inputs, with 100-µA active pullup, and open-drain outputs

I am not sure what to make of this information in terms of the maximum current that can be safely drawn simultaneously from all pins of a port, or in terms of the output impedance at each pin (Which would allow me to estimate the former)

Comment: What are you intending to drive with it? The data sheet implies that a maximum of +/- 4mA to meet the logic levels at the output.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I wish to drive some optocouplers from these pins, the signals go onto some High Voltage control.
Which part of the datasheet helped you figure that out? What is the significance of the 100uA active pull up

Comment: that was in the electrical characteristics on page 7. Section 8.2.1 indicates that port 3 can drive 8mA. I didn't study the data sheet but the active pull up may be controllable by the port configuration register. You may want to look for application notes or data sheets on family members to see if there is more information as this data sheet does not seem very complete.

Comment: A quick scan of the datasheet is confusing. On page 5 it mentions the PUR pin (17) is a CMOS output and can sink or source \$\pm 4\:\text{mA}\$. But on page 29 it says "The PUR driver is a CMOS driver that can provide \$V_\text{DD}-0.1\:\text{V}\$ minimum at \$8\:\text{mA}\$." These two facts aren't consistent, except for one thing -- there appears to be only one pin capable of sourcing a lot of current -- pin 17. The other I/O pins appear to be capable of sinking some milliamps, but not sourcing it. Not surprised, given an 8052 style MCU core.

Comment: Datasheets are not exempt from errors and reporting them to the manufacturer can help fix them, but in this case the part is obsolete.
The current the "open-drain" outputs can sink is provided in the example (8mA), while their programmable pull-up is only good for 100uA.
For the PUR there is contradictory information - the minimum is +/-4mA .  If you want to be safe, you limit yourself to these limits.
The SCL is also listed as a push-pull output and not as an I/O while  a slave can theoretically slow down the I2C clock.   Drive capabilities for the SCL output are missing.